# Bitmap inside a Sprite - But still not clickable? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, sprite, webcam

Basically I've got a bitmap which is an image that the user captures from a webcam which was previously stored as bitmapdata which I converted into a bitmap and added it onto the stage..

From here I want the bitmap to be selectable so I can do other things to it, so I realised I would need to add this into sprite in order to add event listeners onto it.

Having done so, for some reason my application ain't wanting to recognise the events added?

Here is the code I've got..

Bitmap..

```
//Create a new bitmap from the video capture
image = new Bitmap(bitmap,"auto",true);

//Set the width and height properties
image.width=150;
image.height=125;

//Set the stage position
image.x = 430;
image.y = 280;

stage.addChild(image);
```

Sprite..

```
 var imageSprite:Sprite;
 imageSprite = new Sprite();
 imageSprite.x = 200;
 imageSprite.y = 50;
 imageSprite.addChild(image);

 stage.addChild(imageSprite);
```

Event listener:

```
  imageSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, SelectWebImage1);
```

Function:

```
function SelectWebImage1(e:MouseEvent): void {
     trace("Clicked");
}
```

I receive no errors from this but I noticed that when I have that code written in my application, all of the code underneath it doesn't seem to function?

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong, any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried adding image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, SelectWebImage1); but it still doesn't seem to recognise the click though?

Comment: It's possible that you have an object over the top, which would negate click events.

Comment: Some reason when I have the above code added in though, all my other code underneath doesn't seem to work either? Do you have any idea what the cause could be for that? Thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: You'd better just instantiate the bitmap and directly add it to `imageSprite` without any xywh alterations. It's possible that you have your sprite intercept all the click events, and not just those aimed at the displayed bitmap.

Comment: @Marty I think that a `Bitmap` object can not dispatch a `MouseEvent` that's why OP needs to use `Sprite`.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply, I will take a look at your suggestion @Vesper and see if that helps, thanks

Comment: @Vesper Fixed it, Thank you! After hours of trying to solve this.. All I needed to do was remove the x and y properties to fix the problem.. I Appreciate your help, if you post the answer I'll mark the question as solved, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `Sprite`'s dimensions, you implicitly set its scale, and also if you place some graphics by using `width` and `height`, the width and height includes any sprite's children, accounting for their position. You should place that bitmap into `imageSprite` and not set `x,y` proerties for the bitmap, this way you won't have to account for its position inside the sprite to position the bitmap.